# ajax form input file upload loading a separate page in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, form-submit

I am using

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

for my ajax form upload.

When I upload file without the Codeigniter framework this works fine. But when I used it within the frame work it shows me the following error :-

```
HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
```

plus it is actually loading a separate page

Here's my code :-

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = { 
                clearForm: true,
                resetForm: true
            };
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                //alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 

            }); 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);

        }); 
    </script> 

</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br /> 
        <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
        <br />
        <input type="file" value="Share a Pic" name="file" id="file" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
    </form>
</body>
```

For Codeigniter I changed the action to

```
site/submit_myform
```

So it loads site/submit_myform. Site being my controller. other values are being stored in the database

Thanks

Comment: can you use the console of firefox or chrome, go to newtork choose xhr requests and see wich url is used for the ajax request?

Comment: hi, everything is working fine now, the file upload feature and all the input data is being stored. But it is redirecting to a separate page. I tried what u said above, but I am not able to see any url while I submit the form

Comment: i even removed the action from form and then added a url in var options = { part but still it doesn't work

Comment: If you use google chrome developer tools at the bottom you have a black circle press it and then it will turn red, this means will record every request, maybe this way you could see all the requests even after the redirect

Comment: it shows something like   comment
                          /main  i.e for Name/path

Comment: did I answer your question?

Comment: @timpeterson - no, ur solution did not work

Comment: If you want an AJAX form submission but are getting a normal submission it means your javascript is broken somewhere **or** there isn't something there to prevent normal form submission such as `return false` which I suggested in my answer. If there is an error, it could be either client or server side. Can you check the dev tools in your browser to see if there is a JS error or check the `Response` to see if there is a server-side error?

Answer (score 1):

The ajax part isn't working if the page is redirecting. You need to `return false;` during the `on submit` to prevent the page from redirecting.

I would suggest following the [`ajaxSubmit()`example provided in the form plugin.](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit)